# Android App crashes on tablet but not on regular phones?

Tags: php, android, mysql, eclipse

So I created a login functionality for an app using Eclipse, PHP, and MySQL...and it works fine on multiple phones (Xperia Play, Droidx, HTC Thunderbolt), however, I can't get it to work on any tablet that I have tried. (Nexus 7, ASUS Transformer). I keep getting force close errors when I click register new user.

Is something wrong with the resolution? Or does it have something to do with my code?

I used this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my Log:

```
12-01 18:22:14.896: D/AndroidRuntime(10040): Shutting down VM
12-01 18:22:14.896: W/dalvikvm(10040): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416f2930)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at com.groupone.the.health.effect.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:42)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at com.groupone.the.health.effect.library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:61)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at com.groupone.the.health.effect.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:54)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-01 18:22:14.946: E/AndroidRuntime(10040):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT#2:
Here is the code for ".RegisterActivity":

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.androidhive.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnRegister;
    Button btnLinkToLogin;
    EditText inputFullName;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully registred
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);
                            // Close Registration Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // Close Registration View
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: post the relevant code along with the crash log you are getting..

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Logcat? _Anything?_ We're not psychic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. That means you are doing a heavy network operation in your main UI thread. In API Levels below 11 you can do this, but on Android HC+ it's not allowed anymore. You can avoid this by using an [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: For some additional background why it is a bad idea to do network operations on the main thread see http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you making your http request from another thread or async task? since tablets are greater than api level 10. You may be facing a strict mode issue. Try to make your http request in a async task.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be making network traffic in the main thread?  Earlier versions of android allowed you to do this,  but starting with Honeycomb all network access must be done in another thread.  The tablets you mentioned run ice cream sandwich so this is possible.

Very difficult to solve your problem.  Please leave stacktraces and source code.  Your description is very vague.

Comment: I'm really sorry...wasn't sure if this had a very typical easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` means you are making a call on main thread and it has a very easy solution:
at `com.groupone.the.health.effect.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:54)`

use AsynTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do the registration. You will have to separate the UI code from the network code there.

Comment: This is a group project for Senior semester...I'm not great at Android..if I posted the code for .RegisterActivity could you maybe show me exactly how to make the change? Tablet support isn't a requirement..but I would love to be able to get it to work.

Comment: This is not about tablets. Any of the new phones won't run it. (Galaxy S3, HTC One, etc. ...about 30% of all Android devices: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Comment: Ok I see now. Is this a pretty simple solution for me? Or should I just roll with what I have?

Comment: Could you please show me how I could change what code I have to make it work for .RegisterActivity? I would be very thankful!